# Syntax issue while multibinding on CanSelectNextPage of WizardPage-WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit, multibinding, formwizard

I would like to use multibinding on property of WizardPage called CanSelectNextPage.

WizardPage connects to Extended WPF toolkit package.

I did:

On MainWindow.xaml:

```
<xctk:WizardPage x:Name="Page1" PageType="Interior"
                 Title="DB Configuration-Stage 1"
                 Description="Select between create new GFACT environment to update existing gfact database" 
                 Background="#FF27E0E0" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" 
                 Leave="Page1_Leave">
    <WizardPage.CanSelectNextPage>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CanSelectNextPage1}">
            <Binding ElementName ="RadioButNew" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
            <Binding ElementName ="RadioButUpdate" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
            <Binding ElementName ="outputFolder" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay"/>
            <Binding ElementName ="reducedModelFolder" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </WizardPage.CanSelectNextPage>
    <Grid Margin="-5 -10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButNew" Content="New" Margin="5 10" FontSize="13.333"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButUpdate" Content="Update" Margin="5 10" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="13.333"/>
        <Label x:Name="outputFolderLabel" Content="Select destination folder:"  Height="30" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="13.333" Margin="5 10">
            <Label.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FilterConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName ="RadioButNew" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
                    <Binding ElementName ="RadioButUpdate" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Label.Visibility>
        </Label>
        <Label x:Name="reducedFolderLabel" Content="Select reduced model folder:" Height="30" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="13.333" Margin="5 10 ">
            <Label.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FilterConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName ="RadioButNew" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
                    <Binding ElementName ="RadioButUpdate" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Label.Visibility>
        </Label>
        <TextBox x:Name="outputFolder" Width ="200" Height="30" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5 10">
            <TextBox.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FilterConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName ="RadioButNew" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
                    <Binding ElementName ="RadioButUpdate" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBox.Visibility>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="reducedModelFolder" Width ="200" Height="30" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5 10">
            <TextBox.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FilterConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName ="RadioButNew" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
                    <Binding ElementName ="RadioButUpdate" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBox.Visibility>
        </TextBox>
        <Button  x:Name="outputFolderOpenBut" Content="" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Width="30" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5 10" >
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="OpenPL.bmp" />
            </Button.Background>
            <Button.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FilterConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName ="RadioButNew" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
                    <Binding ElementName ="RadioButUpdate" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Button.Visibility>
        </Button>
        <Button  x:Name="reducedModelFolderOpenBut" Content="" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Width="30" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5 10" >
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="OpenPL.bmp" Stretch="Uniform"/>
            </Button.Background>
            <Button.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FilterConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName ="RadioButNew" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
                    <Binding ElementName ="RadioButUpdate" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Button.Visibility>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</xctk:WizardPage>
```

On MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public class CanSelectNextPage1 : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] is bool && values[1] is bool && values[2] is string && values[3] is string)
            if (((bool)values[0] || (bool)values[1]) && (values[2] != null) && (values[3] != null))
                {
                    return true;
                }

        return false;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

An error "Wizard Page is not supported in WPF" appeared on:

```
<WizardPage.CanSelectNextPage>
```

I'm assume it syntax issue- can someone help me please? I'm newbie on WPF..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
<xctk:WizardPage.CanSelectNextPage>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CanSelectNextPage1}">
        <Binding ElementName="RadioButNew" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
        <Binding ElementName="RadioButUpdate" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
        <Binding ElementName="outputFolder" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay"/>
        <Binding ElementName="reducedModelFolder" Path="Text" Mode="OneWay"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</xctk:WizardPage.CanSelectNextPage>
```